# Can Subversion limit a developer to accessing only certain files?

Tags: windows, svn

I need to outsource some programming.  I was thinking of setting up a computer the programmers could Remote Desktop into with a full test environment set up on that computer.

I have never used subversion and was wondering if I could give them access to only certain modules so that could not even see the code to modules they did not need?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Sorry I did not mention we are a windows shop. (offtopic: and I am often sorry we are a windows shop LOL )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that in Windows, the user they use to access the Subversion system can be a normal Windows user, and you can just set up permissions to allow access to folders that way.

Answer (score 1):

> ... if I could give them access to only certain modules so that could not even see the code to modules they did not need?

Sure, at least on directory level when serving Subversion through Apache.

See the [http chapter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch06s04.html#svn-ch-6-sect-4.4) in [The Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

If you're on Windows, Subversion server wrappers like free [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com) make access control brain-dead easy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look in the `conf/authz` file.

Plenty of examples in there.

However, if you are giving them full access to the machine with subversion on it then that won't help stop them...